# Setting private properties of a class using its public methods, c++

Tags: c++, class, methods, properties, private

Something like this:

```
class someclass
{
public:
    someclass();
    ~someclass();

    long   Set(int x, int y);

private:
        int _x;
        int _y;
};

long   Set(int x, int y)
{
   _x = x;
   _y = y;
}
```

But if you just write something like this, the _x cannot be recognized inside Set() function. So how do I setting the private properties of a class using its own methods? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a member function outside of its class definition, you have to scope it appropriately:

```
long someClass::Set(int x, int y)
{
  _x = x;
 _y = y;
}
```

What you wrote defined an unrelated global function `Set`.

Also, the return type of `Set` should probably be `void` (or you must return something from it).

Comment: Thanks you but I got this error: Unhandled exception at 0x00e52309 in IntelIPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Comment: It seems the _x is not initialized, so it is basically a NULL. So it cannot be assigned a value even though x has got the right value.

Comment: @NickTsui Can you show the code calling `Set()`? From the error, I'd guess you're accessing it through a pointer to `someClass` which is `NULL`.

Answer (score 6):

You have a scoping problem there. This should work:

```
long someclass::Set(int x, int y)
{
   _x = x;
   _y = y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is nothing wrong with build, but when run this program, error occur at _x = x; I got this error: Unhandled exception at 0x00e52309 in IntelIPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Answer (score 3):

You have what is effectively a typo.  You have declared one member function:

```
class someclass
{
public:
    long   Set(int x, int y);
```

...but implemented a *completely different*, free function:

```
long   Set(int x, int y)
{
   _x = x;
   _y = y;
}
```

Change the latter to:

```
long   someclass:Set(int x, int y)
{
   _x = x;
   _y = y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you but I got this error: Unhandled exception at 0x00e52309 in IntelIPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Comment: It seems the _x is not initialized, so it is basically a NULL. So it cannot be assigned a value even though x has got the right value.